# Laravel5: How to use @lang in @section?

Tags: laravel

I normally set my page titles like this:

```
@section('pageTitle', 'Awesome Page')
```

I then wanted to change page title based on selected language and tried this:

```
@section('pageTitle', @lang('my_account.pageTitle'))
```

However, I get this error:

```
FatalErrorException in b159db713cb664ba091b07db738bd4c3748de1cb.php line 1: Call to undefined function lang()
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 16):

This works it seems, not sure if it's the smartest way to handle it though:

```
@section('pageTitle', trans('my_account.pageTitle') )
```

Comment: That's pretty much how you'd do it!

Comment: Was looking for it. Thanks!

Comment: Worked well! Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, this way does not allow you to use HTML within the language file. Any idea how to get around that?

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
@section('pageTitle')
    @lang('app.pageTitle')
@endsection
```